# How do I make a div flash from 0 opacity to 1, continuously without clicking?

Tags: javascript, jquery

It's "Scroll Down" text, and I just need it to smoothly flash back and forth from 0 opacity to 1 the whole time the user is on the page.

Here's the HTML and CSS:

```
<div class="begin-scroll">SCROLL<br>
<span>TO BEGIN</span>
</div>

.begin-scroll{
    font-family:'Charliedontsurf';
    font-size:43px;
    color:#FFFFFF;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:0.7em;
    opacity:0;
}
.begin-scroll span{
    font-size:34px;
}
```

This is the code that works for the type of effect I want (minus the continuous flashing):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.begin-scroll').delay(3500).fadeTo(1000,1).fadeTo(1000,0).fadeTo(1000,1).fadeTo(1000,0).fadeTo(1000,1);
});
```

This is the kind of code I want, but the console log was throwing a "too much recursion" error:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
$('.begin-scroll').delay(3500).fadeTo(1000,1,pulsatingOut());
function pulsatingOut(){
    $('.begin-scroll').fadeTo(1000, 0, pulsatingIn());
}
function pulsatingIn(){
    $('.begin-scroll').fadeTo(1000, 1, pulsatingOut());
}
});
```

I'm not too fond of jQuery, so forgive me if this is a poorly put together and/or dumb question. Oh, and if you want to replace the jQuery altogether with plain 'ol javascript to solve this, please feel free, any solution helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `()` from your `complete` parameters in the `.fadeTo` call. You want to simply pass a *reference* of that function, not the result.

```js
;(function($){
  $(function(){
    // store a reference (slight cache improvement)
    var $el = $('.begin-scroll');
   
    // declare the functions
    function pulsatingOut(){
      $el.fadeTo(1000, 0, pulsatingIn);
    }
    function pulsatingIn(){
      $el.fadeTo(1000, 1, pulsatingOut);
    }

    // call first one and have it loop through
    pulsatingIn();
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```css
.begin-scroll { width: 100px; height: 100px; background-color: #f0f; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="begin-scroll"></div>
```

Comment: You Rock Socks!! Works like a charm @brad.

Comment: `jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
 $('.begin-scroll').delay(3500).fadeTo(1000,1,pulsatingOut);
 function pulsatingOut(){
  $('.begin-scroll').fadeTo(1000, 0.5, pulsatingIn);
 }
 function pulsatingIn(){
  $('.begin-scroll').fadeTo(1000, 1, pulsatingOut);
 }
 });`

Answer (score 4):

Must it be Javascript/jQuery? This can be solved in CSS using animations and keyframes.

```css
@-webkit-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
      0%   { opacity: 0; }
      50% { opacity: 1; }
      100% {opacity: 0; }
    }
    @-moz-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
      0%   { opacity: 0; }
      50% { opacity: 1; }
      100% {opacity: 0; }
    }
    @-o-keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
      0%   { opacity: 0; }
      50% { opacity: 1; }
      100% {opacity: 0; }
    }
    @keyframes NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION {
      0%   { opacity: 0; }
      50% { opacity: 1; }
      100% {opacity: 0; }
    }
    
    #box {
      -webkit-animation: NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 2s infinite; /* Safari 4+ */
      -moz-animation:    NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 2s infinite; /* Fx 5+ */
      -o-animation:      NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 2s infinite; /* Opera 12+ */
      animation:         NAME-YOUR-ANIMATION 2s infinite; /* IE 10+, Fx 29+ */
    }
```

```html
<div id="box" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; background-color: red;"></div>
```

Comment: I really do like this answer, and it works beautifully. But, yes, this question was posted under jquery and javascript, and thats the kind of solution I need to keep consistency throughout my site.

Comment: It is far better to use CSS (alone) whenever CSS alone will do the job.  The CSS will work even when JavaScript is disabled.  Although it probably doesn't make any difference, it will be more efficient, too, because it's executed by the browser's native machine language code.  Those jQuery fades work by manipulating the CSS, adding a layer of interpretation that's not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to Brad's answer, but a more basic approach.

As Brad said, you will want to pass a `callback` to the `fadeTo` method.  Callbacks are also known as `delegates`, `function references`, etc.  As soon as you add the parentheses at the end, you are telling JavaScript to execute that function reference.

Since I had already developed my fiddle while Brad was answering, here's what I came up with.  It's not as self-contained, but it works and gives you a simplified idea. I did have to change your text color to black.

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/o5qgq6LL/1/

```js
function pulsatingIn(){
    $(this).fadeIn(1000, pulsatingOut);
}

function pulsatingOut(){
    $(this).fadeOut(1000,  pulsatingIn);    
}


$('.begin-scroll').delay(3500).fadeIn(1000, pulsatingOut);
```

```css
.begin-scroll{
    font-family:sans-serif;
    font-size:43px;
    color:#000;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:20%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    line-height:0.7em;
    display:none;
}
.begin-scroll span{
    font-size:34px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="begin-scroll">SCROLL<br>
<span>TO BEGIN</span>
</div>
```